# ¿Qué código tengo utilizar para el eje y aumente en función de los resultados?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo este código escrito, pero a la hora de correrlo para que me muestre el gráfico no consigo que en el 'eje Y' represente el total de 'GANADO' y 'PERDIDO' que he ido acumulando en el excel. Me podrías decir cómo escribir el eje y. El problema lo tengo al final. Muchas gracias Este es mi código:

```
def estadistica():
    max_row = ws.max_row
    ganado = 0
    perdido = 0
    for name in range(1, max_row + 1):
        print(ws[name][0].value)
        print(ws[name][1].value)
        print('-----')
        if ws[name][1].value == 'GANADO':
            ganado += 1
            print(f'Hay {ganado} ganados')
        if ws[name][1].value == 'PERDIDO':
            perdido += 1
            print(f'Hay {perdido} perdidos')
    print(f'Hay {ganado}  ganados y {perdido} perdido')

    grafico.title('Ganar o perder')
    grafico.xlabel('Total')
    grafico.ylabel('GANADO O PERDIDO')

    x = ['Ganado', 'perdido']
    y = [sum(f'{'GANADO'}', sum('PERDIDO'))]
    grafico.bar(x, y)
    grafico.show() 
´´´

El problema le tengo en el EJE Y **(y = [sum(f'{'GANADO'}', sum('PERDIDO'))]**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y = [ sum( f'{'GANADO'}', sum{'PERDIDO'} ) ]
```

Puede ser que estés necesitando cerrar entre llaves a:

```
{"PERDIDO"}
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver yo haria un par de cambios.

Mas que representar solo la suma en el eje y, representaria la separacion de ambos, tanto de ganado como perdido y luego agregaria otra para el total.

Dejando la ultima parte del codigo que muestras asi :

```
x = ['Ganado', 'Perdido', 'Total']
total = ganado + perdido
y = [ganado, perdido, total]
```

Creo que el hecho de agregar una tercera barra que represente el total le da mas valor al verse de manera clara el resultado final de las operaciones mas que al menos mostrar solo la suma del total que al fin y al cabo es la finalidad de este tipo de graficos.

Quedo atento, cualquier cosa me comentas

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionado!